# Support for Auditable in spring-data-mongodb?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

As far as I know, there is no support for org.springframework.data.domain.Auditable in the spring-data-mongodb project (version 1.1.1.RELEASE).
Does anyone has some tips or references how to implement this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is support upcoming in the next release of Spring Data MongoDB. The implementation not only contains `Auditable` support but also the annotation based support introduced in Spring Data Commons (i.e. the ability to use `@CreatedBy`, `@LastModifiedDate` to be more specific about what shall be set and prevent the need to implement an interface). The relevant JIRA issue is [here](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAMONGO-577), the according commit is [here](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-mongodb/commit/94823500624432de101e464f6adf72d98b37a347). If you want to give it a shot, feel free to grab a snapshot build from our [Maven repository](https://repo.springsource.org/libs-snapshot/org/springframework/data/spring-data-mongodb/1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/).